# What is the cause of this Attribute Error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

I have 2 modules as:

1. `main.py`
2. `get.py`

In `main.py`, I need to call a function present in `get.py` which is `call_get()`.
So I'm trying it this way:

```
import get
get.call_get()
```

But it throws an error as `'Attribute Error'`.
On the other hand, the following code works:

```
import temp
temp.func()
```

function `func` in `temp.py` looks as:

```
import get
get.call_get()
```

I am unable to understand this behaviour. Please guide.

`get.py` code:

```
import requests
import json
import sys
import utils
import error_handler
import get_helper
import os
import pvdata

def call_get():
    try:
        auth_tuple = utils.get_auth_details("get")
        headers = utils.get_header()
        resource_types = utils.get_resource_types()
        namespaces = utils.get_namespaces()

        if resource_types[0].lower() == "all":
            resource_types = utils.append_all_resources()

        get_helper.get_namespace_list(auth_tuple, headers)
        all_namespaces = utils.extract_namespaces_from_list("source")

        if namespaces[0].lower() != "all":
            error_handler.validate_source_namespaces(namespaces, all_namespaces)

        utils.create_file(
            "Namespaces", "All_namespaces_at_source.txt", str(all_namespaces))

        get_helper.generate_json_for_all_namespaces(
            all_namespaces, auth_tuple, headers)

        for resource_name in resource_types:
            if namespaces[0].lower() == "all":
                for namespace in all_namespaces:
                    get_helper.call_all_functions_for_get(
                        namespace, resource_name, headers, auth_tuple)
            else:
                for namespace in namespaces:
                    get_helper.call_all_functions_for_get(
                        namespace, resource_name, headers, auth_tuple)
    except Exception as error:
        filename = os.path.basename(__file__)
        error_handler.print_exception_message(error, filename)

    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    call_get()
```

`main.py` code:

```
import utils
import remote_exec
import post
import get
import error_handler
import os
import handle_space
import socket
import json
from requests import get
import sys
import temp

def only_dest_requires_jumpserver():
    try:
        dictionary = {
            "migration_type": utils.config_data()["source_cloud"] + " to " + utils.config_data()["dest_cloud"]
        }

        utils.update_config_file(dictionary)
        print("\nInitialising " + utils.config_data()["source_cloud"] + " to " + utils.config_data()["dest_cloud"] + " migration...")
        hostname = socket.gethostname()

        if hostname == utils.config_data()["my_hostname"]:
            # get.call_get()
            temp.func()
            print("\nData successfully exported from source to this machine.\nChecking for space availability at jumpserver...")
            print("Done!")
    except Exception as error:
        filename = os.path.basename(__file__)
        error_handler.print_exception_message(error, filename)
```

Comment: Show us the code in `get.py`.  You either have a spelling error, or the function is part of a class or something.

Comment: Do you have circular imports?

Comment: I have updated the question with ``get.py`` code. No cicular imports.

Comment: What is the code of `main.py`?

Comment: I think I have got the answer.
The issue is main.py has 2 get modules as:

``import get``
``from requests import get``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `main.py` has 2 `get` modules as:

```
import get 
from requests import get
```

`get` is being overwritten.....you need to rename your function or use

```
import request
request.get
```

Another simple way is `aliasing` suggested by  [InsertCheesyLine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11323371/insertcheesyline).

```
from requests import get as _get
```

and use `_get`

Comment: Wouldn't aliasing either of the `get` be enough? `from requests import get as _get`

Comment: Indeed, your approach seems to satisfy the OP and is direct. I'll leave my comment for anyone else who searches this.

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine modified by answer to include your suggestion.